# What is the maximum number of edges in a connected graph with no odd cycles

Tags: graph-theory

We went over that the maximum number of edges in a graph with no even cycles is $3(n-1)/2$ by using a spanning tree and making triangles.  Can we do the same thing for this but instead of adding one edge, we would have to add two each time?  But then I am getting stuck, because we also have the theorem that says if it has more then $(n^2)/4$ edges it will have a triangle or odd cycle.  Is the professor just trying to trick us?  Doesn't this mean most edges is the $(n^2)/4$, because if more then has the odd cycle?  And why doesn't this following instead of the $3(n-1)/2$

Comment: Hint, not posted as an answer because I haven't checked it out. With no odd cycles the graph is bipartite. Check out the complete bipartite graph.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd cycles.  You should post an aswer.  andemw01: All you need to do is find the maximum of $(n-m)m$ for $1 \leq m < n$. Your professor didn't trick you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: With no odd cycles the graph is bipartite. Check out the complete bipartite graphs with a fixed total number of vertices.